# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I'm posting json string in the request body with escape characters and mapping it to a model in the controller but it is throwing below exception

> json string : "{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}" 
>    exception
>   can not construct instance of `Entity` (although at least one Creator exists):
>   no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from
>   String value ('{"id":"1","desc":"test"}') at [Source: (String)"
>   "{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}""; line: 2, column: 2]"

but when i use a json string with out escape characters it is working fine json string

```
{"id":"1","desc":"test"}
```

Model

```
class Entity
{
@Id 
String id ;
Map<String, Object> dynamicFields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

@JsonAnySetter
void setDetail(String key, Object value) {
    dynamicFields.put(key, value);
}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Map<String, Object> getDynamicFields() {
    return dynamicFields;
}

public void setDynamicFields(Map<String, Object> dynamicFields) {
    this.dynamicFields = dynamicFields;
}
```

and below is the controller post method

```
@PostMapping("")
ResponseEntity<Entity> create(@RequestBody String jsonString) throws JsonParseException, 
JsonMappingException, IOException {
    objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
     Entity mongoStoredEnity = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,  Entity.class);
//rest of the code ....
}
```

any clue on this why it is accepting json string with out escape characters only?

Comment: The code works for me if I hardcode `objectMapper.readValue("{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}", Entity.class);`. My guess is that the passed in `jsonString` contains something different, maybe escape characters. Can you debug the actual value of `jsonString`?

Comment: i'm sending it from google arc client and actual value is coming correct only you can observe it in the exception message it self

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UNESCAPE String while converting java object to JSON string using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706849/how-to-unescape-string-while-converting-java-object-to-json-string-using-jackson)

Comment: no chance read the question carefully.I'm not able to map to a pojo when i send a valid json string with escape characters from a rest client

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Don't send the leading quotation marks, else the value is interpreted as a string.

You input the wrong value, i.e. your input is actually `"\"{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}\""` instead of the correct value `"{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}"`. I.e. you need to remove the leading and trailing `"`.

EDIT: If you want to test it:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
    final String jsonString = "\"{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}\""; // this throws your MismatchedInputException
    final String jsonStringCorrect = "{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}"; // this works as expected
    final Entity mongoStoredEnity = om.readValue(jsonStringCorrect, Entity.class);
    System.out.println(mongoStoredEnity);
}
```

Comment: no i'm sending json like this from google arc client  "{\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}\"

Comment: sure, please remove the leading and trailing quotation marks to make it a json object, i.e. just input {\"id\":\"1\",\"desc\":\"test\"}

Comment: if i pass like that rest client will complain that it is not a valid json.You can check online whether it is a valid json or not

Comment: Ah, well, yes, but interestingly it's ok for jackson. However, `"invalid{}//json[[["` or anything else that is a valid string is valid json, but you require the object.

Comment: Also: Why do you have those escape chars? And why don't you just have `@RequestBody Entity mongoStoredEnity `?

Comment: i will get data from a service in  that format only .Using @RequestBody Entity  mongoStoredEnity also throws the same exception.I used the same syntax initially .

Comment: But `{\"id\":\ "1\"}` is not valid json? I just used `\"` to escape it in the java `String`, if your input contains thoise backslashes, you probably need to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace backslash with following code.

```
String jsonFormattedString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Then pass it to Object Mapper

Comment: i'm passing a valid json it should work with escape characters also .replacing backslash is an extra operation and will cause performance issues and i'm sending a long json string in my actual context

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
myString.replace("\"{", "{").replace("}\"", "}")
```

With that, you replace the first and the end quote.