# POJO Json object wrapped in double quotes doesn't deserialize to Java

Tags: json, jackson, json-deserialization, objectmapper

My application is receiving json objects from some source and these are wrapped as strings. These are not getting deserialized but throw exception like mentioned below. I have created a sample program to reproduce this. Can someone points out if there is a way to ignore extra quotes around json fields for it while deserializing or object mapper configuration to make it work.

```
  @Test
  void testTrade() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Trade trade = new Trade(2.3, "USD");
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(trade);
    System.out.println(json);
    Trade res = mapper.readerFor(Trade.class).readValue(json);
    Assertions.assertEquals(trade, res);

    String jsonString = "{\"value\":2.3,\"currency\":\"USD\"}";
    Trade res1 = mapper.readerFor(Trade.class).readValue(jsonString);

    String jsonString2 = "\"{\\\"value\\\":2.3,\\\"currency\\\":\\\"USD\\\"}\"";
    
    //This throws exception : Cannot construct instance of `com....Trade` (although at least one Creator exists):
    Trade res2 = mapper.readerFor(Trade.class).readValue(jsonString2);
  }
}

class Trade {
  double value;
  String currency;
  @JsonCreator
  public Trade(@JsonProperty("value") double value, @JsonProperty("currency") String currency) {
    this.value = value;
    this.currency = currency;
  }

//getters, equals, hashcode, toString()
}
```

Exception:

```
    Cannot construct instance of `com....Trade` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"value":2.3,"currency":"USD"}')
 at [Source: (String)""{\"value\":2.3,\"currency\":\"USD\"}""; line: 1, column: 1]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com....Trade` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"value":2.3,"currency":"USD"}')
 at [Source: (String)""{\"value\":2.3,\"currency\":\"USD\"}""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Base Answer** is from [How do I unescape a JSON String using Java/Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706849/how-do-i-unescape-a-json-string-using-java-jackson)

There is an apache common util for unescape strings.

```
   org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
```

But, **in your case**, your string has one more problem, you also need to trim the first and last recurring double quotes. Then you can able to apply unescape util upon.

```
jsonString2 = jsonString2.substring(1, jsonString2.length() - 1);
jsonString2 = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(jsonString2);
```

Hope it will solve your case.